# Python class declaration "positional argument" error

Tags: python, pandas, class, declaration

I'm experimenting with pandas. I'm trying to create a simple object that represents the data i want to work with. To do so I've written the code below to create an object but I'm getting:

> TypeError: test_df() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self

on line 13. I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps something conceptual about the class declaration I'm not getting. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

class ICBC():
   def __init__(self, name, path):
       self.name = name
       self.df = pd.read_csv(path)

   def test_df(self):
       print(self.df.info)


mov = ICBC("matisalimba3","z:\devs\py\movimientos.csv")
ICBC.test_df() <- This is line 13
```

Comment: You mean `mov.test_df()`? Or equivalently `IBC.test_df(mov)`?

Comment: Right. I was calling on the class instead of the instance.. thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've created an instance of your class (using `ICBC(...)`), you need to call the `test_df` method on the *instance*, not the *class itself*.

Change your code so that `mov` is what you call `test_df()` on:

```
import pandas as pd

class ICBC():
   def __init__(self, name, path):
       self.name = name
       self.df = pd.read_csv(path)

   def test_df(self):
       print(self.df.info)


mov = ICBC("matisalimba3","z:\devs\py\movimientos.csv")
mov.test_df()
```

To further clarify what the error is telling you: when you call a method on an instance in Python, a `self` argument is automatically passed. However, `ICBC` is not an instance, so `self` is not passed. This results in the argument error you've seen.

This behaviour means that you could also do this to call the method:

```
ICBC.test_df(mov)
```

However, nobody does this: it's not considered good practice since it makes the code longer and harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
mov = ICBC("matisalimba3","z:\devs\py\movimientos.csv")
mov.test_df()
```

instead of

```
ICBC.test_df()
```

test_df is an instance method, so you need a instance to access it. Your problem is you tried to access the method as it was a class method

Answer (score 1):

`test_df` is an instance method; you need to call it on an instance of `ICBC`, not on `ICBC` itself.  Perhaps you meant to write `mov.test_df()`?